# If $ds$ is not a differential form, can I make sense of its intuitive notation somehow?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, differential

I understand that a line element is not actually a differential form but a $1$-density. My question is: is the notation $ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2$ formal in any way? Can it be interpreted as outer or tensor products? Is it just simply an informal useful way to describe an integrable object?

I think that a straightforeward interpretation of $ds^2$ as the wedge product of two vector valued differential forms is not possible, but is there any other way I can look ar this?

After looking into the other posts related to this same subject, such as [Why is arc length not a differential form?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456212/why-is-arc-length-not-a-differential-form) and [Is $ds$ a differential form?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483191/is-ds-a-differential-form) I still can't find a useful way of thinking about this particular problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$ds^2$ is a *symmetric* covariant $2$-tensor; i.e., this notation is classical shorthand for
$ds^2 = dx\otimes dx + dy\otimes dy$, and we evaluate the line integral $$\displaystyle\int_C ds = \int_C \sqrt{ds^2} = \int_a^b \sqrt{g^*(dx\otimes dx+dy\otimes dy)} = \int_a^b |g'(t)|dt,$$
for any parametrization $g\colon [a,b]\to\Bbb R^2$ of $C$, as expected. Of course, $ds$ is *not* a $1$-form because $ds(v) = \sqrt{ds^2(v,v)}$ is not linear in $v$.

Comment: When you say that $ds^2$ is a rank 2 covariant tensor are you implying that it is a 2-form? because as I understand it forms are just covariant tensors and $ds^2$ is supposed not to be a form.

Comment: $k$-forms are *alternating* (skew-symmetric) covariant $k$-tensors. The metric is a *symmetric* $2$-tensor. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Great answers!